# create a Visualforce page which shows a list of Accounts linked to their record pages

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
  <apex:pageBlock >

  <apex:repeat var="a" value="{!accounts}" rendered="true" id="account_list">
  <li>
  <apex:outputLink value="https://ap1.salesforce.com/{!a.ID}" >

</apex:outputLink>
  </li>
  </apex:repeat>
  <apex:outputLink value="sathiy">
  </apex:outputLink>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

here the problem is outputlink is not displayed,,instead of links,dots are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add any text or Account Name inside `apex:outputLink` then only link will display

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!a.ID}" >
   {!a.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="a">
                <li>
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.ID}">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!a.name}"/>
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </li>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

- The value attribute of apex:repeat is set to the variable loaded by the standard list controller, {! accounts }.
- For each record in that list, one record at a time, apex:repeat assigns that record to the variable named in the ’s var attribute. In this case, that variable is named **a**.
- For each record, the repeater uses the apex:outputLink component to link to the respective record detail page

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this code would solve the issue, if it does so.